# Show only weekends in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to only display weekends in Google calendar and not the week days?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/1jzdH3-qnIY

Comment: May I ask why you need this? There might be other solutions, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by Franck Dernoncourt in the comments, it is not possible. You can [read a write up about it here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/1jzdH3-qnIY).